# Is it a good way to represent used / invaild data by -1?

Tags: java

**Introduction**

I had made a extremely simple simulation on real time shuffling ball and pick ball on some time interval

https://github.com/gaplo917/Mark6-java/blob/master/src/Mark6.java

**What I want to simulate is :**

There are total 49 ball in a machine, the machine will keep shuffling the ball. After a period of time, the machine will open the gate pick a ball out.
Here is the video : http://youtu.be/5QHsYA2lcI0?t=2m2s

---

**What I had written** ( extremely easy version ):
There are 49 ball and I made it for 49+1  space.

Each shuffle of the ball if the ball is shuffle into the extra space.

After a period of time, I will check the extra space to see the ball is swapped into it and pick it out.

Then mark the space with -1  to represent the spaces is no longer valid.

Instead, I should pick a ball randomly but not using an extra space. Just ignore this scenario...

After this work, I will try to use Android Game engine to simulate the gravity and collision for learning purpose.

**Back to my question :**

Is it a good way to represent used data by -1 ? Is it a normal approach in real world application?

Comment: Sure, that's fine. To make your code more readable, you could define a constant `NO_BALL = -1` or something, and assign that instead of just `-1`.

Comment: I don't understand your entire description, but it sounds like you're using -1 as a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)?

Comment: Yep, using -1 as a "nothing" identifier is a common practice (though of course one needs to be sure that -1 can't occur as a "normal" value).

Comment: Only if `-1` is an out-of-band value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more Object-Oriented way to handle this would be to create a BallSlot class with separate members for ball number and for whether it's valid.

It's generally not a good idea to use sentinel values like 0 or -1.  It overloads multiple semantic meanings into a single data value, which complicates parsing the value.  Practically speaking, it means all the code that uses the value becomes riddled with if() statements.

Comment: I had seen android used different integer to represent different situation. I update the .java to become  

public static final int EMPTY_SPACE = -1; 

is this a normal approach in JAVA?

If I use the OO way to implement, would someone judge I am over engineering ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be more Java-like to model the balls as objects, even if for now they only have the one field "id". You may very well want to add other properties (position, momentum, etc, if you will extend this to do physics sim as you indicate), and you will need them to be Objects then!

If you're just using int to represent the balls, yes, it's common practice to do something like "-1 means empty".   Please do not become "clever" and start using "-2" and "-3" to indicated other sorts of things, however. =)